# mysql performance of database access in loop

Tags: mysql, database, performance, rdbms

It is obvious that executing database query in loops has performance issues. but if the query is used as prepared statement, does it make any difference?

What is preferable joining together the tables and get the results or using prepared statement in loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `join` would *almost* always be preferred instead of looping over a result set to get additional results.

Relational Database Management Systems are built for combining related results, and does so very efficiently... additionally, this will you save many round trips to the database, which can become costly if used excessively - regardless of if you're using prepared statements or not.

Answer (score 1):

The overhead to the prepared statements is probably not going to be the escaping of the inputs, it's going to be the connection to the database, or reconnection, or act of sending of the finalized sql statement.  That interface between your code and the relational database is likely to be the slow point of the process more than anything else.

However, for my part, I would generally go for whatever is simplest and most able to be maintained from the start, and only worry about performance if the performance actually shows itself to be slow.  Write the data-grabbing functionality in a separate function or method so that the implementation can change if the performance proves to need optimization, though.

At that point you can then start optimizing your sql, and use joins or unions as alternatives to multiple prepared statements.